# Returning values from a range list without having to flatten afterwards

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following test code to returm values from 2 ranges:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = sh.getActiveSheet();

  var rangeList = ss.getRangeList(["A1:A5","C4:C8"]).getRanges();
  var result = [];

  for (var range in rangeList){
    rangeList[range].getValues().map(function(e){result.push(e);});
  }

  result = result.map(function(e){return e[0];});\\flatten array

}
```

This works fine but I have to flatten the `result` array as the `map` function in the `for` loop returns every value inside its own array. Does anyone know of a way around this? Seems like the last line of code could be made redundant somehow.

Thanks

Comment: Ranges won't always be a single column. The values are always returned as an array over the major dimension consisting of arrays over the minor dimension. So for Spreadsheet Service calls, each element is a row. Each element of that element is a column value. In the general case, scripts absolutely treat values from different rows and columns differently, so it is expected that if *you* want to treat them the same, *you* have to do a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can push item at 0 index in first loop?

```
for (var range in rangeList){
  rangeList[range].getValues().forEach(function(e){ result.push(e[0]); });
}
```